# tangent plane to a surface, does it exist in origo?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, tangent-spaces

I have the following equation and points:

> $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and P=(3,  4, 5)

I calculated the tangent plane to:

> $3x+4y-5z=0$

1. Is that correct?
2. And does the tangent plane exist in origo (0, 0, 0)?
3. Is it a critical point in origo?

Thanks a lot in advance:)

Cheers
Tom

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Instead of asking if your solution is correct, you should show your computations.  First, it's easier for others to verify your solutions than to do it over from scratch, and second, if you made a mistake, we'll be able to point it out, instead of just answering, "No."

Answer (score 0):

This figure is a (double) cone with vertex at (0, 0, 0) (in English that is the "origen").  Yes, the point (3, 4, 5) does lie on that line and the tangent plane at that point is given by 3x+ 4y- 5z= 0.  yes, that plane contains the origin.  In fact the tangent plane at any point on a cone contains the origin.  There is, however, no plane that is tangent to the cone [b]at[/b] its vertex.  The cone is not "smooth" there.

Comment: In English, it's "origin" :)

Comment: Thanks for correcting my spelling errors:)

Is it double because of +/- the square root?

So the "double cone" has a tangent plane at the point given that contains the vertex, but does not have a tangent plane to the vertex/origen? Is that correct?

Thanks you so much for helping me understand:)

Comment: @TomPenny It’s not a double cone. Don’t confuse $\sqrt a$ with the solutions to the equation $x^2=a$: there’s no “$\pm$” there.

Comment: thanks you for clearing that up @amd. I actually was a bit confused:)